# Codenameone rotate display

Tags: orientation, codenameone, display

I am building an application that has 4 buttons on the start screen. Each button opens a new Interaction Dialog.

I want 3 of those dialogs to alway be in portrait mode, and 1 to open, and continue, in landscape mode.

The code of the orientation shall override the user's device configuration.

How would I go about achieving this? It seems trivial, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation or on the net.

What I have tried is

```
Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);
```

but the command does not lock the orientation of the display, at least not in the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator ignores the `lockOrientation` call. Furthermore, its effect is somewhat limited on iOS so it won't work as expected there because of some design decisions that are really hard to change.

In iOS the orientation is usually forced for the entire app using a build hint. You can configure that in Codename One Setting under the iOS section.

This method works more consistently when it's applied globally as it was in the [Uber app](https://medium.com/@Codename_One/what-ive-learned-from-cloning-the-uber-app-b0a7c743c1c1).

Comment: Shai, how would I achieve the display rotating into landscape mode on a button click. I'm working on an Android device.

Comment: In the Android device your code should work. Notice that since the rotation takes place asynchronously you can't rely on it happening by the next line of code...

Comment: Is there a method in CN1 to rotate the screen into landscape mode, Shai?

Comment: It's `lockOrientation` as you used it. `true` for portrait `false` for landscape but it will only work on Android